# How can I use Powershell to make multiple different folder names based on a single variable?

Tags: powershell

I'm a novice to scripting, completely. I mostly hodgepodge from what I can find. I do okay but I can't figure out a good way to do what I'm doing and it's likely I don't know how to phrase the question.

I'm working in powershell and I want to, based on one variable, create multiple folders with that variable in the script. So this is what I have that works, and I'll explain what I want to do instead.

```
$lab1 = "RM112"
$lab2 = "RM113"
$lab1users = "RM112Users"
$lab2users = "RM113Users"
$lab1share = "RM112Share"
$lab2share = "RM113Share"
 
        
New-Item "C:\Labs\$Lab1" -ItemType Directory
New-Item "C:\Labs\$Lab2" -ItemType Directory
New-Item "C:\Labs\$Lab1\$lab1users" -ItemType Directory
New-Item "C:\Labs\$Lab1\$lab1share" -ItemType Directory
New-Item "C:\Labs\$Lab2\$lab2users" -ItemType Directory
New-Item "C:\Labs\$Lab2\$lab2share" -ItemType Directory
```

What I basically want to do is have it to where I just have to populate the lab1 or lab2 blanks, and it creates the folders based on that. So by changing just the $lab1 variable, it would create C:\Labs\Lab1, C:\Labs\Lab1\Lab1Users, C:\Labs\Lab1\Lab1Share."

I feel like I'm overcomplicating this with the things I've tried, seems like it should be simple. I thought maybe concatenate? I could achieve this with a csv file I think but there's gotta be a way without haha.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you only need 1 array for the lab folders and then an inner loop that will concatenate the lab element with `Users` and `Share` to create the destination folders. If you use `-Force` with `New-Item` you don't need to worry if the directories don't exist.

```bash
$labs = @(
    'RM112'
    'RM113'
)

foreach($lab in $labs) {
    foreach($item in 'Users', 'Share') {
        $newItemSplat = @{
            Force    = $true
            Path     = [System.IO.Path]::Combine('C:\labs', $lab, $lab + $item)
            ItemType = 'Directory'
        }
        New-Item @newItemSplat
    }
}
```

This would create 4 folders with the following paths:

```
C:\labs\RM112\RM112Users
C:\labs\RM112\RM112Share
C:\labs\RM113\RM113Users
C:\labs\RM113\RM113Share
```

Comment: @MattRPSB gladd it helped :)

Comment: haha hey, so I'm trying to make this as easy as possible for people who come behind me. Is there any way to get it to work like this? Where I'd only have to get them to put in the folder/room name at the top and it'll do the rest? Your code was easy to understand so I was able to replicate that to creating OU containers and subcontainers and everything. 

`$RM1 = "Test4"
$RM2 = "Test5"
$labs = @(
    '$RM1'
    '$RM2'
)`

Comment: @MattRPSB seems like you just need to remove the quotes from the variables inside `@(..)` instead of `@( '$RM1'..)` just use `@( $RM1..)` so the variables can expand. If that wasn't the question, please ask a new one